# overriding a wordpress plugin function defined inside class

Tags: php, wordpress

im trying to add :

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_pluggable_function' ) ) {
    function my_pluggable_function() {
        /* Some code goes here */
    }
}
```

to a plugin that has its functions defined within a class.

it seems that as soon as I do a IF in a class definition, php throws an error.

Comment: What kind of error? Have you tried [method_exist()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) ?

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the error ?

Comment: seems like I can't edit my own question - so here is the error: arse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /Users/hugues/Projets/BangMarketing/caroulemontreal/git/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/common.php on line 1094

Comment: happens when I add the function exist testy... I tried with method_exist() too - same results - it bugs right at the if.

Comment: all the common.php code is within a class GFCommon {} class - that seems to be the difference with other plugins where the addition of function exits works...

Comment: its part of the gravityform wordpress plugin which im trying to override a function from.